# Very long training time on a simple CNN

Tags: neural-network, pytorch

```
#building a convolutional neural network for images
    #hyperprams
learning_rate = 5e-3
in_channel = 3
num_classes = 57 
batch_size = 24
class CNNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,num_classes):
        super(CNNet, self).__init__()
        #Using 3 inchannels for RGB bvalues 
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3,
                               out_channels=15,
                               kernel_size= (3,3),
                               stride=(1,1),
                               padding= (1,1),
                               bias=True)
        #in channels on second layer must match out on first layer 
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels= 15,
                               out_channels= 30,
                               kernel_size=(3,3),
                               stride = (1,1),
                               padding=(1,1),
                               bias=True)
        #can use max pooling to reduce image size to 13 x 13 
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2,2)
        #last level is fully connected with num out channels * original image dem /2
        self.fc = nn.Linear(30 * 13 * 13 * 3, num_classes)
        
    def forward(self, x):
            x = f.relu(self.conv1(x))
            x = f.relu(self.conv2(x))
            x = self.pool(x)
            x = x.reshape(x.shape[0], -1)
            x = self.fc(x)
            return x
#instantiate the class object of CNNet
cnn = CNNet(57)
cnn_optimizer = optim.Adam(cnn.parameters(), lr = learning_rate)
#training the CNN 

for epoch in range(1):
    for i, (data,target) in enumerate(train_loader):
     cnn_optimizer.zero_grad()
     #forward
     outputs = cnn(data)
     loss = criterion(outputs, target)
     #backward propigation
     cnn_optimizer.zero_grad()
     loss.backward()
     cnn_optimizer.step()
```

Im having an issue with training a convolution neural network using a custom data.
I have about 10000 color images all of size 26X26 Im trying to use to train the model to predict 57 different classes.
When Im running on the custom images class train in taking hours to complete. Currently 12 hours and it hasn't finished.
Im assuming I have something wrong in the training process that's causing such a long run time, But Im not sure where.

Comment: Do you have GPUs on this machine? I don't see you moving the model or data into GPU. If not, the time might be reasonable.

Comment: I have the same sentiment as @joe32140, but would also advise you to use a timing library like `tqdm` around your training loop to see how fast your model is training. It's as simple as using `for i, (data, target) in enumerate(tqdm.tqdm(train_loader)):`.

Comment: When I go to check with torch.cuda.is_available() I get False, Can I not use the GPU on a Mac?